# Hide cell after transferring view controller through segue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, segue

After changing the text through a segue, I tried to hide a cell through the segue. This did not work. Here is my code:

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    TerminalsViewController *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"firstSegue"])
    {
        transferViewController.term1Text = @"Joe Smith";
        transferViewController.term2Text = @"555-555-5556";
        transferViewController.term3Text = @"06/27/1984";

    }else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"thirdSegue"]){
        transferViewController.term1Text = @"John Smith";
        transferViewController.term2Text = @"555-555-5556";
        transferViewController.term3Text = @"06/27/1972";
        transferViewController.cell1.hidden = YES;

    }

}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prepareForSegue:

```
TerminalsViewController *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"firstSegue"])
{
    transferViewController.term1Text = @"Joe Smith";
    transferViewController.term2Text = @"555-555-5556";
    transferViewController.term3Text = @"06/27/1984";

}else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"thirdSegue"]){
    transferViewController.term1Text = @"John Smith";
    transferViewController.term2Text = @"555-555-5556";
    transferViewController.term3Text = @"06/27/1972";
    transferViewController.hideCell = YES;

}
```

TransferViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic) boolean hideCell;
```

TransferViewController.m:

```
@synthesize hideCell;
```

TransferViewController.m:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (hideCell) {
    cell1.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to press the check button to the left after the cooldown period expires (:

Comment: There you go! Thanks so much.